# How can I append json data if object key is equal to a predefined value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have got an ajax GET request that pulls in data through a loop. What I am trying to achieve is to get posts that are relevant but are not in the predefined id value of the current post you are on. So I have this function below:

```
var _permId = $('#work-area').data('current-id');    
var getRelatedPosts = function() {

            $.ajax({
              url: '/wp-json/posts?type=case-studies&filter[taxonomy]=awards&filter[term]='+_awardsPart+'',
              success: function ( query ) {

                //List some global variables here to fetch post data
                // We use base as our global object to find resources we need
                // _permId is the var that tells me the current id of this post
                var posts = query;
                postFull = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                    //terms.push(term);
                    var postObject = posts[i];
                    postFull.push(postObject);
                    for (var key in postObject) {
                        //console.log(postObject[key]);
                        if (postObject[key] === _permId)  {
                            console.log('this is the same as this post');
                        }
                    }
                };
              },
              cache: false
            });

        };
```

What I want to do is not allow any content through if the post object id is the same value as `_permId`.

Here is an idea of the json that is retrieved with keys and values:

```
Object {ID: 4434, title: "new brand case", status: "publish", type: "case-studies", author: Object…}
```

The ID is the value I want to set an argument against.

Comment: Does your problem solved ?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't to loop on the object if you just want to check the `ID` :

```
...
postFull = [];
for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var postObject = posts[i];
    postFull.push(postObject);
    if(postObject.ID === _permId) {
        //they have the same id
    }
};
```

EDIT : 
To get the datas you want you can use [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) :

```
var newArray = $.grep(posts, function(e, i){return e.ID !== _permiId;});
```

or in pure JS

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
    var p = posts[i];
    if(p.ID !== _permId){
        newArray.push(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah yeah sorry. How could I only show data related to the objects that don't have that id though as I asked above. This does not answer the question, it's a suggestion and should be a comment below really.

Comment: I think that was the answer. You want an array that does not contain the item with _permId, and that is what @Sacreyoule's $.grep and pure JS answers show. Or are we missing something?